# Create view that snaps to grid on mouse drag

Tags: cocoa, view

Have a view that is added as subview and want it to drag around the other view that is gridded. In order to keep it on the grid lines it needs to snap to the grid specs.(which is 10px).

I have this but it is based on wherever I click the mouse on the view and not the view size itself.

```
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    float step = 10.0; // Grid step size.
    NSPoint newDragLocation = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    newDragLocation.x = step * floor((newDragLocation.x / step) + 0.5);
    newDragLocation.y = step * floor((newDragLocation.y / step) + 0.5);
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",newDragLocation.x,newDragLocation.y);

    NSPoint thisOrigin = [self frame].origin;
    thisOrigin.x += (-lastDragLocation.x + newDragLocation.x);
    thisOrigin.y += (-lastDragLocation.y + newDragLocation.y);
    [self setFrameOrigin:thisOrigin];
    lastDragLocation = newDragLocation;
}
```

Need it based on view size because I am adding multiple views that need to align. Thanks!

Comment: "based on view size" is unclear. Can you elaborate? Also a visual example would be helpful.